# Reboot alternatives

Tags: samsung, reboot, samsung-galaxy-note-3

So my situation is this. About a week or so ago my power button fell out and I dont want to get it repaired until I back up my stuff. For some reason my pc hasn't been able to link to back up but that has been since i got the phone.
So anyway, my internet has gone down on my phone so I want to restart it (turn it off and on). The turning off is fine but I'd rather not sit there for an hour doing the unpluck power, pull out and reinsert battery to make it turn on again. I know on Blackberry phones there is an app as standard which acts like the power button but is there one (or an option somewhere) for android where I can restart my device? The only option I can see is a factory reset option.

My phone is a Note 3 if that helps.

Comment: What is your android version? Do you have root access? There are many soft-key applications that give power button functionality, but they need root access. When you have root, you can even enable on-screen navigation bar and use hardware home button as power button (maynot work on some devices) by tweaking some `.kl` file in `/system/usr/keylayout/`.

Comment: Internet suddenly started working again so im going to look up getting an app to deal with this incase there's a relapse while I backup. Thanks for the info Bharat G